# SQL Server : how to write a relative query that always give you the data from last two quarters of your current quarter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a relative query that gives you the data from the last two quarters of your current quarter? I want to write this query in SQL server then run for tableau dashboard.

Here is my query example to work with:

```
SELECT
    a.CloseDate AS 'Close Date',
    CONCAT(YEAR(a.CloseDate),' Q',DATENAME(qq,a.CloseDate)) AS 'Close Quarter'
FROM 
    DATABASE
WHERE 
    a.CloseDate < DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 4, 0) 
    AND a.CloseDate > DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

My current result is：

```
Q4 2021, Q1 2022, Q2 2022, Q3 2022
```

I want:

```
**Q2 2021, Q3 2021,** Q4 2021, Q1 2022, Q2 2022, Q3 2022
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: 1) provide sample data  2) explain your logic

Comment: What about `a.CloseDate >= DATEADD(qq, -2, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))`

Answer (score -1):

try using over(partition) with a row_number and call it row id then get the max row id and previous row id for the quarters.

```
SELECT
TOP(2)
SUM(AMOUNT) AMT,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART('QUARTER',EVENT_DATE) 
ORDER BY DATEPART('QUARTER',EVENT_DATE)) ROW_ID
FROM TABLE
order by ROW_ID desc
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Thank you